# Как вывести на экран данные от источника json, через метод fetch в react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const CardsClient = () => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  fetch('https://project-2be95-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/executors.json')
    .then((response) => {
      response.json()
        .then((json) => {
          setCards(json)
          console.log(json)
        })
    })

  return ( <div> 
    {Object.keys(cards).map((e) => {
      return ( <h1 key = {e.id}>{e} < /h1>)
    })} 
    </div>
  )
}
export default CardsClient;
```

Comment: Что, собственно, собой представляет это JSON? Добавьте в вопрос это JSON и опишите, как эти данные должны отображаться на странице

Comment: На базе данных есть некоторое количество данных которые, как задумано выводятся на сайт карточками. но у меня получается только вывести ключи юзера

Comment: В этом json данные, ключ - значение из базы данных. Ключи рендерятся, а вот как данные обработать, картинки, текст и тд?

Comment: В вопрос добавьте пример json который получаете и хотите отрендерить. Тоотко причем тут картинки не понятно и что за текст?

Answer (score 0):

> Как вывести на экран данные от источника json, через метод fetch в react js?

Например вот так...

```js
const url = 'https://project-2be95-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/executors.json'
//
function App() {
  const [cards, setCards] = React.useState({})
  React.useEffect(_ => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => setCards(res))
      .catch(console.log)
  })
  return <ul>
    {Object.keys(cards).map(k => <Item key={k} data={cards[k]} ttl={k} />)}
  </ul>
}
//
function Item({data, ttl}) {
  return <li>
    {ttl}
  </li>
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

Comment: В первом варианте тот же результат, выводятся в рендер только ключи